# How to get text from the alert box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to grab a text from the alert box shown below. This alert box appears hovering above the url bar.
Below is an example of my framework assertion:

```
verifyDisplay("'"+ driver.switchTo().alert().getText() + "'", By.xpath("xpath").
```

I am not sure, how to grab `xpath`, `id`, `name` of this alert box, since there is none.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Add just this code and check if it retrieves the alert text (after alert is visible of course) or not. `System.out.println("Alert text is: " +driver.switchTo().alert().getText());`

Comment: @Subh, it shows in the console, but this is not what I am trying to achieve though. I want to grab this message by its xpath, id, name or whatever and show it in the testNG reports.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a method in Alert interface which gives you the text of the alert box message. As below:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.getText();
```

[Alert API javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html)

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I have tried this method, as you can see above in my assertion, but scenario is kinda different from a regular gabbing of the text. I need to insert this text into the assertion, and the assertion recognizes the messages only either with xpath, name, or id

Comment: is there a public url where we can check what are you trying to achieve? Can you please tell us what are you asserting, the text that appears on the alert box or what?

Comment: I am asserting the text that appears above. In our framework, the xpath must match with the the text. I am not sure how would i grab this. I can log this info, but it won't show in the testNG reports.

Comment: By text you mean: "The page at https://xfpqa1uiadm1.realads.com says: Are you sure you want to delete this pause/restart record?". That is what you are asserting right, whether this matches the expected alert message? If that's the case then you should be able to get that text and assert it. In the line of code that you've written By.Xpath('xpath'), are you asserting the text with an object of class By?

Comment: I agree with you, but where is the xpath or this alert box? That's what i am not able to figure out. And, Yes, I am trying to grab the text "Are you sure you want to delete this pause/restart record?"

Comment: If you are looking for alert box in DOM you will not he able to find it there. as far as i know alert boxes are created by functions. check here http://www.pushtotest.com/selenium-tutorial-for-beginners-tutorial-2. you will have to change your assertion point. you will have to make assertion based on the expected alert message instead of comparing a string with an object of By class.

Comment: Very nice and detailed explanation. Definitely accepted and voted up.

Comment: Alert API doc redirecting to `404` page. updated link https://static.javadoc.io/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.52.0/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html

Answer (score 1):

Just import the "org.openqa.selenium.Alert" lib and use below code to get the text from dialog boxes.

```
Alert confirmation = driver.switchTo().alert();
String alerttext = confirmation.getText();
System.out.println(alerttext);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do one thing here get the HTML source in string and then find the 'alert(' and then we can substring the message inside the alert box
ex-

```
var htmlString = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
if(htmlString.includes('alert(')){
    var indexOfAlertBeginning = htmlstring.indexof('alert(');
    var stringFromAlert = htmlstring.substr(indexOfAlertBeginning);
    var indexOfAlertEnd = stringFromAlert.indexof(')');
    var alertMessages = stringFromAlert(0,indexOfAlertEnd);
    console.log(alertMessages);
}
```

Please Try this and tell me if this workable

Answer (score -1):

Qus) How can the message in the alert box be retrieved?

Ans) storeAlert() command can be used to retrieve the message from the alert pop-up and store it in a variable.