# How to get Text from Leave site Alert?

Tags: java, selenium, alert

How to get Text from Leave site Alert?

I tried Switching to it using `driver.switchTo().alert()`, but I  am getting blank text.

I have also attached screenshot of alert:[image: alert Text]

Please help me in this regards.

Below is my code::

```
public class TestMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F://chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onbeforeunload");
        driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click here to go to w3schools.com")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because this alert text is generated by Browser and not provided by website. If you change the browser, the alert will appear but text may change. There is also case of extra text in alert 'Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs' again generated by Browser. Not sure if selenium supports such cases yet, as I don't have documentation saying that.

Comment: can you just try it without using `driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");` may be it will work?

Comment: @akshay patil,Link text is available inside frame,To get alert I need to click on that link

Comment: To click on particular link which generates alert, `driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");` is required, because its under iframe

Comment: @BlueStar Possible duplicate of [How to get text from the alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206453/how-to-get-text-from-the-alert-box)

Comment: @jithinkmatthew it is possible to duplicate,but even write down proper documented code it will return empty string.

Comment: @Dhru'soni, I tried. yes, it is returning an empty string. Is it possible to get text by using `JavascriptExecutor`?

Answer (score 0):

The URL given in the original issue description. The observed behavior is by design according to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

**returning a custom message string from onbeforeunload handler is deprecated,** including chrome. A standard message is display to the users, while the string returned from the event handler is ignored and not receivable from chromeDriver.