# Get text from leave site alert using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

Is there any way to get the *text* from an alert in JavaScript?

Below I have attached the screenshot of an alert.

Actually I am trying to automate a website using selenium and java and selenium isn't able to handle such alert.

I wonder whether the JavaScript has solution to such alerts.

I am not aware of JavaScript syntax and code styling so posting only a question. Please excuse me for this.

```
driver.switchTo.alert().getText()
```

only works for if it is a JS alert,if it is browser alert then it doesn't work

ALERT EXAMPLE:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an alert exists using WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467471/how-to-check-if-an-alert-exists-using-webdriver)

Comment: @Evan..driver.switchTo.alert().getText() only works for if it is a JS alert,if it is browser alert then it doesn't work

Comment: linking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253818/how-to-get-text-from-leave-site-alert

Answer (score 1):

You should try this, with Selenium:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.getText();
```

Comment: No this works only for nor JS alert,it it is browser alert this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this within javascript is using the confirm popup. It has generic 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons which I don't believe can be edited and is formatted according to the users web browser. To use  the confirm method you write:

```
if (confirm("Do you really want to leave here?"){
   //do whatever
}
```

Comment: we can generate a alert using window.onbeforeunload also